# Getting error Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'PER_COUNTRY' on line 1

Tags: php

```
<?php
$name=DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, "US");
print_r($name);
?>
```

Working fine in localhost. But when i am trying it online i m getting error Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'PER_COUNTRY' on line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a PHP 5.3 or greater function. So your server version on your live server is not >= PHP 5.3

See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php

Comment: Actually i need particular country's timezone at one time. I am getting all timezone here $name=DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
print_r($name);

Comment: Is there any way to get particular country's timezone except it.

Answer (score 2):

Check your versions of PHP: PER_COUNTRY was added with 5.3.0

Comment: Actually i need particular country's timezone at one time. I am getting all timezone here $name=DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
print_r($name);

Comment: Is there any way to get particular country's timezone except it.

Comment: The PECL Geoip extension has http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-time-zone-by-country-and-region.php

Comment: You can get the code from http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php/ and the tarred zip file contains a timezone.php file with switch statements for returning countries and their timezones